# How to make visible the click action on Button?

Tags: android, xml, android-studio

When we click the Button,the background change color to some black transparent color. But, when I change the background of Button, the user can't see the visual reaction of Button when he click on them.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: please try this...   android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you !

This is my answer and i use it well.

```html
<ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:color="@color/blackTrans"
    tools:targetApi="lollipop">
    <item android:id="@android:id/mask">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@color/blackTrans" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</ripple>
```

@color/blackTrans is a black color with transparency

Answer (score 2):

For v21 and above you can use:

**bg_button.xml**

```
<ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:color="?android:colorControlHighlight">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_normal" />
</ripple>
```

In your Button:

```
<Button
    ...
    android:background="@drawable/bg_button" />
```

Important: if button has *disable* state ripple effect ***not*** shows.

More: https://guides.codepath.com/android/ripple-animation

Comment: how to use that?I am Beginer please.

Comment: @Boris I updated my answer. Please, let me know it is that you need?

Comment: in your xml file in button set background of that button to this